# Serverbased auth solution for solana wallet

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, nextjs

I created my first opensource project: serverbased login + auth through solana message signing with the T3 stack (nextjs, next-auth, trpc & prisma)

https://github.com/mattiprive/solana-login-t3-stack

I was wondering if people had suggestions for security / would like to contribute improvements to this project.

Thanks in advance